# Hibernate DB2 Returns First Charector while using NativeQuery

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, db2, hibernate-native-query

I am facing the following problem while using Hibernate Native Query to fetch data from DB2 CHAR field.

I have a table structure and data as follows.

```
 CNTRL_4 COLUMN_ID PARAM
 ------- --------- --------------------
       1         1 10                  
       1         2 12                  
       1         3 true                
       2         1 10                  
       2         2 13                  
       2         3 false               
       3         1 10                  
       3         2 16                  
       3         3 true
```

CNTRL_4 and COLUMN_ID is number, But PARAM is CHAR(10).
If I run the following query manually (From Eclipse SQL Plugin) it fetches the proper result.

```
SELECT CNTRL_4, COLUMN_ID, VALUE AS PARAM FROM MY_TABLE_NAME
```

But if I run the same query with Java Code (Hibernate Native Query) Then I am getiing following Result.

```
[{CNTRL_4=1, COLUMN_ID=1, PARAM=1}, 
 {CNTRL_4=1, COLUMN_ID=2, PARAM=1}, 
 {CNTRL_4=1, COLUMN_ID=3, PARAM=t}, 
 {CNTRL_4=2, COLUMN_ID=1, PARAM=1}, 
 {CNTRL_4=2, COLUMN_ID=2, PARAM=1}, 
 {CNTRL_4=2, COLUMN_ID=3, PARAM=f}, 
 {CNTRL_4=3, COLUMN_ID=1, PARAM=1}, 
 {CNTRL_4=3, COLUMN_ID=2, PARAM=1}, 
 {CNTRL_4=3, COLUMN_ID=3, PARAM=t}]
```

Please look at the **PARAM** data, it is **only the first character**.

I am using following Java Code

```
String sql = "SELECT CNTRL_4, COLUMN_ID, VALUE AS PARAM FROM MY_TABLE_NAME";
SQLQuery query = hibernateUtil.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(sql);
query.setResultTransformer(Criteria.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP);
List<Map<String, Object>> data = (List<Map<String, Object>>) query.list();
System.out.println(data);
```

I also searched on Google and found this [blog post](http://www.scriptscoop.net/t/27b929d7fd0a/hibernate-returns-only-first-character-of-char-data-type-column-in-db2.html), which is same as my problem. As per as I can remember I had solved this problem by typecasting on SQL query. But right now I forget that what I did and not able to solve it now.

Please help.

**UPDATE:** 
Problem solved by type casting. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By type casting we can solve the problem as follows

```
SELECT CNTRL_4, COLUMN_ID, RTRIM(CAST (VALUE AS VARCHAR(10))) AS PARAM FROM MY_TABLE_NAME
```

**Explanation:**

> Since VALUE column is defined as CHAR on DB2 and Hibernate is checking
>   the type of the filed while using transformer
>   **Criteria.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP**, then it is casting the data to Charecter. So it is returning the first character only.

But while selecting, if we change the type to **VARCHAR** then my problem is getting solved.

Please let me know if there is any disadvantages.

Answer (score 2):

Try without the transformer, so change your query to:

```
String sql = "SELECT CNTRL_4, COLUMN_ID, VALUE AS PARAM FROM MY_TABLE_NAME";
SQLQuery query = hibernateUtil.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(sql);
List data = query.list();
System.out.println(data);
```

That should just pass the query to the underlying DB2 driver, so it should work, unless the DB2 driver doesn't recognize the `false` value as a String.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But it will be dificult to fetch the column because my column name are dynamic and is being decided from another query. For simplicity of problem I did not mention on my question. Though I have figured out the solution. We can type cast to VARCHAR. Please see my answer.